# C++ : Turn char array into a string that is printed

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

just a beginner student learning basic C++. I'm trying to figure out the best way to:

1. Turn a char array Name of 20 into a string that can be printed.
   I found in other Stack Overflow topics to use "str()" such as "str(Name)", but it always comes up 'identifier not found'.

   ```
   cout << "Name:" << str(Name) << endl;
   ```
2. Set a char array of 20 characters. For some reason, the following gives me errors when declaring. I've tweaked it so many times, but I cannot get why it won't give.

   ```
   TESCStudent.Name[20] = {'S','u','p','e','r','P','r','o','g','r','a','m','m','e','r','\0'};
   ```

Full code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Step 1
struct StudentRecord
{
char Name[20];
//Accessor
void printInfo() const;
};

void StudentRecord::printInfo() const
{
cout << "Name:" << str(Name) << endl;
}

int main()
{
//Step 2
StudentRecord TESCStudent;
TESCStudent.Name[20] = {'S','u','p','e','r','P','r','o','g','r','a','m','m','e','r','\0'};

//Step 3
TESCStudent.printInfo();

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `std::cout << Name;`?

Comment: An array of `char` is already a string that can be printed. Test it out by doing `cout << Name;`.

Comment: Why are you using `char[]` instead of `std::string`?

Comment: @clcto *"just a beginner student learning basic C++..."*

Comment: @0x499602D2 More reasons to use `std::string`. `char[]` (as opposed to `std::string`) is definitely not "*basic*" C++.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Ah, thanks! I didn't know that. :) Now I just can't figure out the second question why I can't init an array like: 
TESCStudent.Name[20] = {'S','u','p','e','r','P','r','o','g','r','a','m','m','e','r','\0'};

without getting errors

Comment: @SamuelGarcia You are obviously lacking the very basics of C++, while trying to do non-basic tasks. [Please read a C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) first.

Comment: Because C++ doesn't work like that, unfortunately. You can use `strcpy(TESCStudent.Name, "blah");`

Comment: @SamuelGarcia Because a braced initializer `{...}` can only be used in certain contexts, that is not one of them. Also, the `[20]` shouldn't be there. Instead, change `Name` into `std::string Name;` and do `TESCStudent.Name = "SuperProgrammer"`

Comment: C++ (and also plain C) will do you the favor of recognizing a string constant such as "This is a string" as an array of `char`, so that you don't have to enclose each individual character in quotes when it is used as an initializer. It will even provide a null terminator character. Just the same, I'd recommend using `str` instead of `char[]`.

Comment: @Jefffrey Sorry, I'm just learning and starting, and well, what better place to ask than here?

Comment: @SamuelGarcia I'm glad it worked! But be clear I agree with the other posters. `std::string` is a lot easier to use.

Comment: @NeilKirk it may be, but the requirement for the coding called specifically for char array of 20 characters, so I'm stuck with it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are at a very beginner level, just use `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

struct StudentRecord {
    std::string Name;
    void printInfo() const {
        std::cout << "Name:" << Name << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    StudentRecord TESCStudent;
    TESCStudent.Name = "SuperProgrammer";
    TESCStudent.printInfo();

    _getch();
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de915706ea5ebb4e)

Comment: @SamuelGarcia: Why is it not what you need? Don't let the "Given that you are at a very beginner level" confuse you. I'm sure it was intended in the opposite sense: C++ beginners tend to overuse char arrays, whereas experienced programmers appreciate the benefits of `std::string`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Both beginners and experienced programmers (especially beginners) should use `std::string`. `char[]` is something you may want to study later in the years. C++ beginners tend to overuse `char` arrays, because there are terrible tutorials out there that advocate such a thing (often together with `new` and `new[]` overuse).

Comment: @Jeffrey: I think the also overuse it because they either come from C or from a newer language where arrays are not very dangerous in the first place, or because they assume that a built-in feature must be the first choice.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I was required and instructed to use char[]. That's why I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax like this:

```
char Name[20] = {'S','u','p','e','r','\0'};
```

is used to initialize a variable when you define it.  However, in your case,

```
StudentRecord TESCStudent;
TESCStudent.Name[20] = ...;
```

You've already defined it on the line before, so you can't "initialize", you have to "assign" it.

This is pretty much why you use `std:string` instead of `char[]`.